# Using jQuery how do I select a range of rows?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Does a jQuery only solution exist for selecting a range of rows from a table?

I know `eq`, `lt`, `gt` exist, but I'm looking for a combination of those selectors.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can apply more than one filter at a time, although the 2nd filter applies to the results of the first, so the following would highlight starting from the 4th row (skips 0..2), and highlight for 3 rows (includes 0..2):

```
$('#t tr:gt(2):lt(3)').css('background-color', '#f00');
```

Answer (score 6):

> Because :gt() is a jQuery extension... using :gt() cannot take advantage of the performance... For better performance in modern browsers, use $("css-selector").slice(index) instead.

Which says, it's better to use native array method `slice` to achieve the goal.

`$('ul > li').slice(start, end).css("color", "blue")`

Direct link: http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery [filter](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter); one form of this takes a callback function as an argument — you can write any complex code in it for the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nthChild](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild#index) selector with an equation argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain your 'eq', 'lt', 'gt' and this will progressively filter each successive returned array.