# jQuery remove range of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, row

Let's say I have a table with these rows:

```
<table>
    <tr id="before_dynamic_rows"></tr>
    <tr id="after_dynamic_rows"></tr>
</table>
```

Using jQuery, I insert automatically generated rows (search results) before the after_dynamic_rows row. How can I delete a range of rows, namely - you guess it - the ones between the row with the id `before_dynamic_rows` and the row `after_dynamic_rows`? (In order to be able, after having inserted them, to remove them and insert different ones.)

```
var response = ajax.responseText;
$('#after_dynamic_rows').before(response);
```

That's how I insert the new rows. Considering the first answer: how can I assign a class to whatever the response text may be?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059625/using-jquery-how-do-i-select-a-range-of-rows

Comment: What is the response you are adding? I assume your response is html generated on the server? If so, then you need to modify the server code that is generating the html that you are appending and add the class information before sending it back to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on a literal interpretation of the question with the idea that the only rows which should be removed are those rows that are in between `#before_dynamic_rows` element and `#after_dynamic_rows`.

See working version at: http://jsfiddle.net/7wBzd/

```
var $rows = $("tr");
$("tr:lt("+ $rows.index($("#after_dynamic_rows")) +"):gt("+ $rows.index($("#before_dynamic_rows")) +")").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would assign a class to those added rows to make them easy to select, but you could select all tr children and use the 'not' method to remove the two you want to keep.

```
$("table tr").not("#before_dynamic_rows").not("#after_dynamic_rows").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("table tr:gt(0)").not("#after_dynamic_rows").remove();
```

[**Try it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Przn/)

Note if `#after_dynamic_rows` is the last row, then you can just do:

```
$("table tr:gt(0)").not(":last").remove();
```

or:

```
$("table tr:gt(0):not(:last)").remove();
```

...and if there are rows before `#before_dynamic_rows`, just do:

```
$("table tr:not(#before_dynamic_rows, #after_dynamic_rows)").remove();
```

Comment: Yours is significantly prettier than mine. But what if there are rows before `#before_dynamic_rows` ?

Comment: Urgh - there are endless possibilities. I think I'll leave it at what I've answered now!