# change background-color td with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to change background-color td with jquery ?

I need to change the background-color column one in row two and three and four

my table :

```
<table class="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
              <td>td2</td>
              <td>td3</td>
              <td>td4</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td >td1</td>
              <td>td2</td>
              <td>td3</td>
              <td>td4</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
              <td>td2</td>
              <td>td3</td>
              <td>td4</td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
              <td>td2</td>
              <td>td3</td>
              <td>td4</td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
              <td>td2</td>
              <td>td3</td>
              <td>td4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ug34K/)

How to do it with jQuery?

Comment: `$('tr:eq(1), tr:eq(2), tr:eq(3)', '.myTable').find('td:first').css('background', 'red')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery how do I select a range of rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059625/using-jquery-how-do-i-select-a-range-of-rows)

Comment: @adeneo Great solution except it doesnt't take into account the first `tr` within the `thead` thus highlighting the 1st, 2nd and 3rd cells. Adding a `tbody` to the selector resolve this. 
`$('tr:eq(1), tr:eq(2), tr:eq(3)', '.myTable tbody').find('td:first').css('background', 'red')`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the nth selector in jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
$( "table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)" ).css("background-color", "blue");
$( "table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1)" ).css("background-color", "blue");
$( "table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1)" ).css("background-color", "blue");
$( "table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(1)" ).css("background-color", "blue");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ug34K/5/)

Answer (score 2):

I found:

`$('table.myTable tr:gt(1):lt(3)').find('td:first').css('background-color', 'red');`

demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33eWz/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myTable tbody tr:lt(4):gt(0)')
         .children('td:first-child').css('background-color', 'lightblue');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ug34K/4/)

This gets the `tr` with index between `0` and `4` => `1,2,3`

```
tr:lt(4):gt(0)
```

Comment: Why not gt0:lt4 ? More natural order, no?

Comment: @mplungjan `gt0:lt3` yeah, I just think weird sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to the tds you are concerned with. A good name for the class would be something that describes why you are highlighting. Then you could just add a statement in css that will handle that. Or if you want to change the color via jquery you could do the following.

```
//Assuming highlighter is your added class name and red is the color you want to change to. 
$('td.highlighter').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Your html for tr would look like this

```
<tr>
  <td class='highlighter'>td1</td>
  <td>td2</td>
  <td>td3</td>
  <td>td4</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If would use this code :

```
$('.myTable tbody tr').filter(function(i){
    return {1 : true, 2 : true, 3 : true}[i];
}).children(':first-child').css('background-color', 'red');
```

But of course, it would be easier to use class.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ug34K/7/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest using jQuery for this kind of styling because it can be a performance issue when ran and if the user has JavaScript disabled, it won't render properly.

What I suggest is using actual CSS to accomplish this task.  If it's absolutely necessary to use JS for it, then adding and removing a class from an element would probably be better.

Find an example of what I'm talking about below.
http://jsfiddle.net/F7hnL/

**CSS**

```
.myTable tr.highlight td:first-child {
    background-color : red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
              <td>td2</td>
              <td>td3</td>
              <td>td4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td>td1</td>
              <td>td2</td>
              <td>td3</td>
              <td>td4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="highlight">
                <td>td1</td>
              <td>td2</td>
              <td>td3</td>
              <td>td4</td>
        </tr>
           <tr class="highlight">
            <td>td1</td>
              <td>td2</td>
              <td>td3</td>
              <td>td4</td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
              <td>td2</td>
              <td>td3</td>
              <td>td4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```