# How do you select a range of tr from a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I find myself frequently in need of selecting a range of tr's from a table. For example, often times, the first tr is the headers of a table and the last tr is the footer/paging numbers of a table, and I don't want to select either of these two.  I know I can do

`$("#mytable>tbody>tr:gt(0)")`

to skip the first tr, but that will include the last tr, which is the paging number row in my case.

What is the most efficient way to get tr's whose indices are greater than 0 and less than the length of the collection? In other words, I want all tr's except the first and the last in the collection.

Any idea?  Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059625/using-jquery-how-do-i-select-a-range-of-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:gt` (greater than) and `:lt` (lower than) can be used with negative numbers to count backwards

```
$('#mytable tr:gt(0):lt(-1)')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GD8mp/)

As a sidenote, there are `thead` and `tfoot` elements specifically for headers and footers in a table

Comment: Thank you very much. Asp.net server control GridView does not seem to render it that way.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, ASP and some other frameworks have their own way of rendering tables, that's why I added it as a sidenote, as it's not always possible to change the table.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
 $('#mytable > tbody > tr').not(':first').not(':last')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use slice :

```
$('#mytable > tbody > tr').slice(1, -1);
```

Negative index goes to the end.

http://jsfiddle.net/VpC2V/

Comment: A bunch of good answers, thank you very much. I think the answer by adeneo and karl-andre suit my need the best. the :not filter is cool, but it is not as flexible, unless we can say :notlt(3):notgt(5). :)

Answer (score 2):

You should try using thead, tbody and tfoot to separate out your table content.  That will let you easily select tr's for the table content:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>header_col1</th></tr>
        <tr><th>header_col2</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>val1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>val2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td colspan=2>footer</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Now the selector becomes very apparent:

```
$(".table tbody tr")
```

Comment: Yes, that's very very true. But I am dealing with some asp.net server control generated html.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('#mytable > tbody > tr:not(:first):not(:last)')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7yS5D/

Answer (score 1):

Try using this method:

```
$('#mytable > tbody > tr').not(':first').not(':last')
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. It would be nice if we can do something like this:  $("#mytable>tbody>tr").gt(2).lt(5). What do you think?