# JQuery - Select range of elements

Tags: jquery

I have got a problem. I need to select all elements which are after some element and before another element. Here is example:

```
<div>
    <span id="first"></span>
    <span id="second"></span>
    <span id="third"></span>
    <span id="fourth"></span>
    <span id="fifth"></span>
    <span id="sixth"></span>
    <span id="eight"></span>
</div>
```

And I want to get all elements from `#second` to, for example, `#fifth`. Maybe a function like `$('div').children().selectRange(1, 4);` exist, but what is the name of this? Thanks for help.

Comment: Please have a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059625/using-jquery-how-do-i-select-a-range-of-rows

Comment: Look into .slice() https://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

Comment: Thanks you MathieuDormeval and remixdesign you both helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically youre looking for the slice function:

`$("div span" ).slice(2,5).remove();`

In my example I am removing the items you wanted, but you can do whatever you need with them after you slice them.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rtk4bosz/

If you want to work with the items use the following where each $(this) is the reference to the item you selected:

```
$("div span" ).slice(2,5).each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pe5b814a/

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```js
$('#second').nextUntil('#sixth').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span id="first">1</span>
    <span id="second">2</span>
    <span id="third">3</span>
    <span id="fourth">4</span>
    <span id="fifth">5</span>
    <span id="sixth">6</span>
    <span id="eight">8</span>
</div>
```